# "Fixed default value provided" after upgrading to Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-1.8

Django 1.8 now has some problem detection for models, which is nice.  However, for one warning that it is giving me, I understand the problem, but I don't understand how the hint that it is giving me is any better.

This is my (bad) model field:

```
my_date = DateField(default=datetime.now())
```

and it's easy to see why that's bad.  But this is the hint it's giving me:

> MyMoel.my_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
>           HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`

So, it says to use `timezone.now`, but how is that any better than `datetime.now`?  They're *both* "fixed default" values... `timezone.now` just *returns* a datetime instance, which is a fixed value...

I suspect that it actually wants me to insert some sort of flag that says "use `timezone.now` *later*".  But that's not what the hint says... so what is that flag?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The function `datetime.now()` is currently executed as soon as your code is imported, i.e. when you (re)start your server. All subsequent model instances will have the same value.

Instead, you should pass a callable function to `default`, that is executed each time a model instance needs a default value. The hint wants to convey that you should literally use `DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)` without the parentheses.

The message is slightly misleading, but Django doesn't know whether you used `datetime.now()` or `django.utils.timezone.now()`.

Comment: So giving it any callable will make the validator happy (i.e. I could pass it either `datetime.now` or `timezone.now`, or anything that is a function that returns a date)?

Comment: Yes, any of them should make the validator (and ultimately, you) happy.

Answer (score 11):

The difference between `timezone.now()` and `datetime.now()` has been explained well in the above answers.
However, the reason you're getting an error is because you are running the function which will set the default time as the time while applying migrations to the database.

All you had to do was use,

```
my_date = DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

instead of

```
my_date = DateField(default=datetime.now())
```

In the above method, the `timezone.now` function will be called while inserting/ modifying an Object.